# Different types of rain in Chinese?

Tags: word-choice, vocabulary, word-requests

Inspired by [this question](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/662/words-for-strong-or-weak-rain-sprinkling-drizzling-pouring) on the Spanish stack exchange
Things like *drizzle*, *mist*, or *downpour*?

Comment: What have you found so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many types of rain in Chinese vocabulary

雨: rain

煙雨: misty rain

微雨: drizzle

毛毛細雨/ 毛毛雨/ 微絲細雨: very light rain/ drizzle

細雨 : light rain

雨霧: rain and fog

過雲雨: brief rain

長命雨/ 長雨 long lasting rain

晴雨/ 晴天雨: sunny sky rain

夜雨: night rain

連夜雨: all night rain

分龍雨: narrow area rain (you can see clear sky few miles away)

大雨: heavy rain

傾盤大雨/ 滂沱大雨/ 豪雨:  heavy rain/ downpour

驟雨: sudden rain

局部地區性驟雨: regional sudden rain

全國性大雨: nation wide heavy rain

陣雨: intermittent rain

暴雨: severe rain/ heavy downpour

狂風暴雨: strong wind and severe rain

暴風雨/ 雨暴: rain storm

雷雨: thunder and rain

熱帶雨 : tropical rain

冷雨: cold rain

冰雨: icy rain

春雨: spring rain

夏雨: summer rain

秋雨: autumn rain

冬雨: winter rain

[梅雨](https://www.hjenglish.com/new/p166348/): plum season rain (of middle and lower reaches of the Yangtze in  late spring and early summer)

山雨: mountains rain

平原雨: rain over the plain

海上雨: rain over the sea

天降甘霖/ 甘霖: life giving rain from heaven (classical term)

及時雨: needed rain that falls in time (idiom for "help that comes in time)

黑雨 : black rain (highest level of warning in the rainstorm warning system in Hong Kong)

Comment: Many thanks for this answer !